# How to query using vertexId if vertex is made using composite key in scala gremline

Tags: scala, cassandra, datastax-enterprise, datastax-java-driver, gremlin-scala

We are using this lib to query dse graph.
https://github.com/mpollmeier/gremlin-scala

1. we can query and get vertex using vertexId if vertex primary key just single key like UUID.
   for `ex. g.V("veretxId=UUID,~label=vertexLabel")`
2. But if vertex primary key is made composite keys for
   ex.

   ```
       addressTD : UUId
       postCode: Int
       sName: String
       lName: String.
   ```

now vertex primary key is composite key of these four values.

3. Now if query in Datastax Studio and get vertex using this query

   ```
   g.V("{sName=\"TREVALLYN\",lName=\"TREVALLYN\",~label=tasLabel,postCode=7250,addressID=ad71d33c-0aaa-4014-a381-c189c30d45c5}")
   ```

it will return vertex in datastax studio.

4. While using https://github.com/mpollmeier/gremlin-scala this lib.
   Its seems it is not working. I am sending vertexId in a prescribed format like this

   ```
   "{sName=\"TREVALLYN\",lName=\"TREVALLYN\",~label=tasLabel,postCode=7250,addressID=ad71d33c-0aaa-4014-a381-c189c30d45c5}"
   ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I found a solution for that.
Use java linked hash map in scala to generate vertexId and pass it to the scala gremlin query.

```
val javaLinkedHashMapVertexId = new java.util.LinkedHashMap[String, Any]()


//Putting values in hashmap
val vLabel =
  javaLinkedHashMapVertexId.put("~label", "vertexLabelName")
val pKeyLocaName =
  javaLinkedHashMapVertexId.put("localityName", "lName")
val pKeyPostCode =
  javaLinkedHashMapVertexId.put("postCode", postCode)
val pKeyStreetName =
  javaLinkedHashMapVertexId.put("streetName", "sname")
val pKeyAddId =
  javaLinkedHashMapVertexId.put("addressID","addressID")

val vertex = graph 
  .V(javaLinkedHashMapVertexId)
  .head()
```

Vertex variable will fetch vertex from dse graph using linked hashmap